# Drawing basic shapes on an image in a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I draw basic shapes on an image in a WP8 app depending on where the user touches the image

Example:

User takes a photo using the camera, it appears in the app (currently using an image control for this), then the user touches a point on the image and a fixed size circle or rectangle appears there. I should be able to store the location of the rectangle and display the rectangle.

Comment: This question is too broad, you need to try something first and come back with a more specific problem that you are having trouble with

Comment: @musefan I guess there would be a specific control that allows for manipulation of images, that's what I'm looking for and am stuck on. specifically, which is the appropriate control to start with